# Child style of css

Tags: html, css

I need some 'derivative' css which is a child of my parent css. I want to import all of attributes of 'parent' css to my 'child' css.
I can't find a solution.

E.g.

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

.more_red {
    color: red;
    border: 2 px solid red;
}
```

Is it possible to do something familar my pseudocode?

```
.red{
    color: red;
}
.more_red <SOME TEXT WHICH SAYS 'THIS CSS IS A CHILD OF .red'>{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class='more_red'>texty text</p> <- this only I Need 
<p class='red more_red'>texty text</p> <- not this
```

**EDIT** I need to create a css which consists of all of 'parent' css properties.

Comment: are you trying to select the children or direct child of parent class.?

Comment: I what to copy all of 'parent' css attributes.

Comment: in sass you could extend a class using @extend, but in css you cannot do it. Is it `.more_red` a child of `.red`? if so you could at least  inherit the colour with `color: inherit`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan `color: inherit` is not needed in case of parent child, as it is inherited by default

Comment: yes, but not always:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwxVyM - if you don't inherit the colour, the link is blue.

Comment: Add your HTML structure to the question... makes us help understand what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only way to inherit/importing the styles defined in one rule to another in CSS is cascading. You cannot use extend as in LESS in CSS.

For inheriting the properties from other element, the parent-child hierarchy is necessary.

You can use `direct child` selector `>`

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
.red > .more_red {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

or descendant selector

```
.red .more_red {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

By doing this, the styles of parent are inherited by children.

You can also use global selector `*`.

Ex. For setting the font-family across the site

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

You can also use `element/type` selector.

Ex. To set the style of all the anchors

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: he wants to import the style defined for .red inside .more_red class.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan That's what cascading does, it inherits all the properties from its parent

Comment: @tushar I think he wants to extend the properties from a css class to another: those elements are not ancestor or child. they could be completely unrelated, as far as I understood

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan That cannot be done in CSS, in LESS you can. But I still think _cascading_/HTML hierarchy is the right approach here rather than adding multiple classes

Comment: @Tushar I have to use a css from a template. But the js code uses my custom css. It is rather difficult to change the code.